# Manifest for Value Type in a Map gives type Nothing

Tags: scala

How can I get the manifest for the second type parameter in a Map?
E.g., the following function:

```
  def asMap[T <: AnyRef]()(implicit m : Manifest[T]) : Map[Int, T] = {
    println(m) // Nothing
    ...
  }
```

invoked as:

```
val map : Map[Int,String] = asMap()
```

the implicit m-parameter is bound to **`Nothing`**
Doing the corresponding with an Array:

```
  def asArray[T <: AnyRef]()(implicit m : Manifest[T]) : Array[T] = {
    println(m)  // java.lang.String
    ...
  }
```

invokes as:

```
val arr : Array[String] = asArray()
```

the implicit m-parameter is bound to to `java.lang.String` - as expected

Could anybody, please, explain?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's because `Map` is covariant in its second parameter: `Map[A, B+]`, whereas `Array` is invariant in its type: `Array[T]`.

Comment: And because Scala picks the most restrictive type to start with (i.e. `Nothing`) and widens only if it needs to.

Comment: So, is possible at all get hold of the actual type?

Comment: @Harald - `val map = asMap[String]` does what you want.  Or you could pass in the actually-created map where there is no longer any choice of which type to use.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what you're doing - how can you get the paramenter if you don't have a Map as an argument?

```
def getManifest[A,B: Manifest](map: Map[A,B]) = manifest[B]

val map = Map(1 -> "one")
getManifest(map) //Manifest[java.lang.String] = java.lang.String
```